# Passing arguments to fsquirt.exe

Tags: windows, cmd, bluetooth

On Windows, `system32\fsquirt.exe` launches the Bluetooth file transfer dialog.

Is there a way to launch fsquirt.exe with a path as an argument, so that it behaves like `"Send to -> Bluetooth Device"` in Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 2):

It is probably not exactly what you are looking for, but a little closer to it

```
fsquirt.exe -send
fsquirt.exe -receive
```

Comment: thats very helpful. Where did you get this info?

Comment: I was hoping that there are such parameters and found them out by trial and error. I could not find a corresponding documentation from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

As usual the MS documentation about their tools is sparse. I only found two parameters one could pass but none does what you need. They have no help in the command line for fsquirt so I pressume there are no more parameters to pass the initial dialog.

If you really need this I'd suggest a third-party tool to bypass the first dialog.

From personal experience I can recommend `DisplayFusion`. Within DF you can set rules, whenever a Window with certan criteria (like Window-Title, Window-Class, ..) opens up, to start custom actions. You can set predefined actions or even write your own in C#.
I had a similar case and wrote a small C# script that simulates a keypress whenever a specific window opened. It's quite easy and not as deep as AutoHotkey for example. But it's quite a lot things to do regarding the quest.

`Send to -> Bluetooth Device` can be 'clicked' by pressing `ALT + S`

Comment: Unfortunately, a third party tool does not fit my use case: I'm attempting to invoke the dialog in an application programmatically for a path that the user chooses.

Comment: Then you **might** need to implement libraries for the bluetooth interface and build the feature yourself.